# tmux - how to resume a suspended session? No such command like resume-session or something like that

Tags: linux, tmux

After a tmux session is suspended by ctl+z, is there anyway to resume it? It does not have resume-session or similar command.

Answer (score 2):

`ctrl-z` suspends the current process.

You can see the list of current processes with the command `jobs`

You can resume the most recent process with `fg`, which means foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found out that..

1. find out you PID which is pending using the command -

   ps aux
2. restart that PID using below command -

   kill -CONT PID